# Promise.all inside try-catch block - error not caught

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise.all

I saw some similar thread on SoF, but they didn't seem to be the exact same thing.
I'm new to javascript, so I might be missing something obvious.

The following code:

```
async function funcThatThrowsError() {
    throw new Error('some error');
}

(async () => {
    try {
        await funcThatThrowsError();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error caught');
    }
}
```

Works as I expect, meaning the `catch` clause is really catching the error thrown inside the `funcThatThrowsError`.

However, in this code:

```
async function funcThatThrowsError() {
    throw new Error('some error');
}

(async () => {
    try {
        Promise.all([funcThatThrowsError()]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error caught');
    }
}
```

The `catch` clause doesn't catch the error. Why is that?

Note that if change the above example to be:

```
async function funcThatThrowsError() {
    throw new Error('some error');
}

(async () => {
    Promise.all([
        funcThatThrowsError().catch((e) => {
            console.log('caught error');
        }),
    ]);
}
```

Then this `catch` clause does catch the error.
My questions are:

1. Why does it happen?
2. Does it mean that when working with `Promise.all` i must define a `.catch(...)` function to every promise I pass to `Promise.all` otherwise if any promise will throw an exception is won't be caught anywhere and essentially crash my application?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `await Promise.all(...)`?

Comment: Why did you remove the `await`? Nothing to do with using `Promise.all` or not.

Answer (score 3):

> The catch clause doesn't catch the error. Why is that?

You aren't `await`ing anything, so the only errors you will catch are synchronous errors. If you want to catch a promise rejection with `try/catch`, you must `await` that promise. Promise.all creates a promise, so `await` that.

```
try {
  await Promise.all([funcThatThrowsError()]);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error caught');
}
```